# jquery: remove submenus from menu items

Tags: jquery

simple request: remove/delete submenus from first and fourth main menu item. my not working code:

```
$('#main-menu ul li(:nth-child(1),:nth-child(4))').remove(.dropdown-menu);
```

as menu's html is quite long, i will insert here only beginning part of it, the whole is available [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/7onepLmz/)

html:

```
<div id="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Piirissaar</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Welcome to Your Site!</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Kasulik info</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Toitlustus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Majutus</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">Puhkajale</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Meist</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">MTÜ Piirissaare Turism</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: try $('#main-menu > ul > li(:nth-child(1),:nth-child(4))').remove(.dropdown-menu);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why use jq for this ? you can use css 
just add :

```
#main-menu ul li:first-child ul,#main-menu ul li:nth-child(4) ul { 
display:none
}
```

plus i added `{display:block}` to `#main-menu ul ul` so you can see that it's working

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/5f4u73rm/)**

or if you really want to use jq , see here : **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/e9zaj1pn/)**

jq code :

```
$('#main-menu ul li:nth-child(1),#main-menu ul li:nth-child(4)').find('ul').remove();
```

Comment: CSS solution don't remove ul **totally**, but your jquery solution is perfect! thank you Mihai T!

Comment: oh. i didn't know you wanted to remove it totally . :) glad i was of help. cheers

Answer (score 1):

first of all you miss some quotes:

```
remove(.dropdown-menu)
```

should be

```
remove('.dropdown-menu')
```

apart from this I would remove the drop downs as follows:

```
$('#main-menu ul li').eq(3).find('.dropdown-menu').remove();
```

hope this helps

Comment: `.get(3)` what is this supposed to do?

Comment: it will return the element on index 3. Even though i can't find documentation on jquery's page, chrome console outputs the following:$('div').get: function (e){return e==null?this.toArray():e<0?this[this.length+e]:this[e]}

Comment: Well, `.get()` is well documented: https://api.jquery.com/get/ and returns the native DOM node. To get the *"index"* you can use `.eq()` or `:eq()`

Comment: Probably you're missing my point, but once you return a JS DOM Element, you cannot nest any more `.find` or other jQuery methods to it.

Comment: You are right, i edited the answer to use eq instead of get

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#main-menu ul li:nth-child(1)').remove();
$('#main-menu ul li:nth-child(4)').remove();
```

for reference https://plnkr.co/edit/7evgZcNKKajb7Lb8PY9v?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something you should not use any JavaScript for. But if you have to, try not to mix it too much with CSS and first of all, check the syntax!

```
var lis = $('#main-menu').find('ul').find('li');
lis.eq(0).remove('.dropdown-menu');
lis.eq(3).remove('.dropdown-menu');
```

If you have no OrderedList you can even omit .find('ul').